# Best way to insert into database?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, design-patterns

I have a requirement where I need to insert into database from the object which has information about table name and values for each column.
Could you please give suggestions on the best way to implement this with Hibernate.

Java Classes

```
public class InsertDataDetails {
  public String tableName;
  public List ColumnDetails> columnDetails;
}

public class ColumnDetails {
  public String columnName;
  public String columnValue;
}
```

At present I am thinking to create a native query and execute it with Session.execute query. However I am looking for better design where we can use DTO classes and hibernate features.

Answer (score 1):

Although your question doesn't mention Spring, I think it's worth calling out the [Spring Data](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa) project.

This provides you with very powerful repositories for persistence, without requiring any implementation beyond declaring an interface.

For example:

```
 public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {}
```

gives you a fully working DAO-like object, for `User`s, with methods such as:

```
List<User> findAll();
User findOne(Long id);
User save(User entity);
```

In order to use this however, you'd need to follow @Duffymo's advice, and model your classes around the objects they represent, rather than their persistence.

Comment: +1 for recommending Spring.  It's an excellent idea, but I'll bet it's over the head of the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We are using Spring too and also have an implementation class similar to the one you have mentioned. Could you please explain about "model your classes around the objects they represent, rather than their persistence".

Answer (score 0):

All of these proposals are far too relational-centric and simplistic.  I'd recommend that you abandon this approach.

You should be thinking about objects in terms of the problem you're trying to solve, not persistence.  If you want to use Hibernate, it can map your OO representation of the problem onto a relational schema.

I'd also recommend that you read Martin Fowler's [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) to see how persistence problems are commonly solved in terms of objects.

Google for Data Access Object.  Here's a simple generic one that's easy to implement with Hibernate and extend:

```
package persistence;

public interface GenericDao<K, V> {
    V find(K id);
    List<V> find();
    K insert(V value);
    void update(V value);
    void delete(V value);
}
```

Persistence in terms of objects has been solved many times over, as best as it can be done.  What you've proposed does not represent a meaningful improvement over the state of the art.

Comment: The last paragraph of your post seems overly harsh, and not fitting with the spirit of Stack Overflow.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/

Comment: Thanks for the response. We do already have an implementation class for the similar interface you have mentioned. The problem is how to create the DTO Objects(<V>) from the InsertDataDetails class.

Comment: Don't use DTOs; just use your model classes.